# Retrieving data from PHP multidimensional array with JQUERY

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like that in a PHP page:

```
$page["1"] = array("element1","element2","element3","element4");
$page["2"] = array("element1","element2","element3","element4");
$page["3"] = array("element1","element2","element3","element4");
```

I need to retrieve some data from this array in a JAVASCRIPT file (JQUERY).

How can I import for example the elements4 `$page[1][3],$page[2][3],$page[3][3]` ?

I have seen many examples here with JSON but not like this one...

Comment: Technically, although not good practice you could set the Javascript array e.g. `var myArray = <php>` code in your script. However, I would recommend writing a server-side request that you can call in JavaScript with XHR / AJAX

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you(Filename: getdata.php):

```
<?
if($_GET['ajax']==1){
$page = array(
                   array("element1","element2","element3","element4"),
                   array("element1","element2","element3","element4"),
                   array("element1","element2","element3","element4"),
                   );

echo json_encode($page);
}else{
?>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="getdata" >Get Data</button><div class="jsdata"></div>
</body>
  <script>
$('.getdata').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"getdata.php?ajax=1",
        success:function(data){
            var res = eval("("+data+")");
            $('.jsdata').html("$page[1][3],$page[2][3],$page[3][3] respectively:"+res[0][3]+","+res[1][3]+","+res[2][3]);
        }
    })
 });
  </script>
</html>
<? } ?>
```